# The service “spamd” appears to be down

Tags: server, cron, email, services, timeout

I keep recieving emails from my Cpanel host with this content

```
The service “spamd” appears to be down.
Server  server.domain.com
Primary IP Address  **********
Service Name    spamd
Service Status  failed ⛔
Notification    The service “spamd” appears to be down.
Service Check Method    The system’s command to check or to restart this service failed.
Number of Restart Attempts  4,197
Service Check Raw Output    (XID cw5v6t) The “spamd” service is down.

The subprocess “/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_spamd” reported error number 69 when it ended.
Startup Log Aug 11 13:23:14 server.domain.com systemd[1]: Starting Apache SpamAssassin™ deferral daemon...
Aug 11 13:23:14 server.domain.com spamd[2484254]: config: no rules were found! Do you need to run 'sa-update'?
Aug 11 13:23:24 server.domain.com systemd[1]: Can't open PID file /var/run/spamd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Aug 11 13:23:24 server.domain.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache SpamAssassin™ deferral daemon.
Aug 11 13:23:24 server.domain.com systemd[1]: Unit spamd.service entered failed state.
Aug 11 13:23:24 server.domain.com systemd[1]: spamd.service failed.
Memory Information  
Used    2.33 GB
Available   1.33 GB
Installed   3.66 GB
Load Information    1.81 1.33 1.05
Uptime  18 days, 2 hours, 44 minutes, and 13 seconds
IOStat Information  avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          15.69    0.03    0.83    0.06    0.00   83.40
Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda               7.61        89.52        62.18  140104959   97317450
dm-0              7.95        89.49        62.18  140053472   97313940
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00       2204          0
Top Processes   
PID Owner   CPU %   Memory %    Command
1691    mongod  43.44   36.81   /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
2484789 gishehnews  8.52    0.71    /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php-cgi
2484770 gishehnews  5.99    0.71    /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php-cgi
2484757 gishehnews  3.68    0.71    /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php-cgi
2479641 root    1.93    1.63    python posts_processor.py
Configure Monitor Settings:
https://server.domain.com:2087/scripts/srvmng#service-chkservd

Configure chkservd:
https://server.domain.com:2087/scripts2/tweaksettings?find=chkservd

Disable HTML notifications:
https://server.domain.com:2087/scripts2/tweaksettings?find=chkservd_plaintext_notify

The system generated this notice on Tuesday, August 11, 2020 at 9:00:22 AM UTC.

“Service failures (ChkServd)” notifications are currently configured to have an importance of “High”. You can change the importance or disable this type of notification in WHM’s Contact Manager at: https://server.domain.com:2087/scripts2/editcontact?event=chkservd

Do not reply to this automated message.
```

actually I have some cronjobs in my host and I have set them a time out using `/usr/bin/timeout -s 2 72000`  to less than an hour, and they run every hour.
can anybody help me understand this email and stop recieving it?
thanks

Comment: Did you run `sa-update` like the error message says? Do you have a valid rules file?

Comment: @waltinator yes I have run sa-update and i get command not found

Comment: Does this server have low RAM?